# Unix command to view job by user

Tags: command

I want to view the job with respect to user account say kate. What is the command should I use?i am using unix server

eg. `ps -u kate` is correct

Comment: What do you mean by jobs?  You mean processes?

Comment: job: task run by user

Comment: The command pstree <user> can show you the tree of process run by user if that what you're looking for !

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work on Unix Like systems :

```
ps -au<username>
```

list all the process for the mentioned user.